# Group layout with label truncation

Tags: apache-flex

I have a group that holds two labels. The text in the labels change dynamically, sometimes with a long text. If I use width=50% for the labels, this may lead to unused lost space like the example below, if one label requires less than 50%. How do I layout the labels so that the maximum space available is used (i.e. the sum of label width = 100% and one or both labels truncate their text if needed) ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application
  xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
  <s:HGroup width="200">
    <s:Label width="50%" text="Label1" maxDisplayedLines="1"/>
    <s:Label width="50%" text="Label2: some very very long text" maxDisplayedLines="1"/>
  </s:HGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Since the HGroup has a fixed width, you could set `maxWidth` on both Labels to `100` and remove their `width` values. But I presume you're looking for a more generic solution.

Comment: Yes. For the example I set HGroup width="200" but in my application, the group has a variable width.

Comment: You can always bind `maxWidth` to be half the `width` of the container: `maxWidth="{containerHGroup.width / 2}"`

Comment: If you bind maxWidth to be half the width of the container, doesn't this constrain the layout manager with a unique solution, i.e. 50% to each, and it is the same as doing width=50% ?

Comment: Except that, if the text is smaller than the 50%, the Label will not take up all available space, but only the space it needs. I thought this was the behaviour you desired, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<s:HGroup width="200" gap="5" id="container">
    <s:Label text="Label1: so" maxDisplayedLines="1" showTruncationTip="true" maxWidth="{container.width/2}"/>
    <s:Label text="Label2: some very very long text that i want to display" maxDisplayedLines="1" maxWidth="{container.width/2}" showTruncationTip="true"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But now there is wasted space on right of label2, i.e. label2 is limited to 50% whereas it could use more space and be less truncated. My goal is to truncate as little as possible

Comment: that code works... when I use a short label1, label 2 gets truncated to fit in 200 width.  when I use a short label2, label1 gets truncated.  if I use short label 1 and short label2 they still always fits a 200 width.  I don't know what you are saying is still wrong. Am I missing something in your question?

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I am trying to maximize the use of space so that minimum truncation occurs. Let's take the extreme case: if label1 is empty, then label2 should fill the entire space.